# python-scapy: how to translate port numbers to service names?

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

A TCP layer in Scapy contains source port:

```
>>> a[TCP].sport
80
```

Is there a simple way to convert port number to service name? I've seen Scapy has `TCP_SERVICES` and `UDP_SERVICES` to translate port number, but

```
print TCP_SERVICES[80] # fails
print TCP_SERVICES['80'] # fails
print TCP_SERVICES.__getitem__(80) # fails
print TCP_SERVICES['www'] # works, but it's not what i need
80
```

Someone know how can I map ports to services?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is something you need to do frequently, you can create a reverse mapping of `TCP_SERVICES`:

```
>>> TCP_REVERSE = dict((TCP_SERVICES[k], k) for k in TCP_SERVICES.keys())
>>> TCP_REVERSE[80]
'www'
```

Comment: it's a strange dictionary (scapy.dadict.DADict object) and it doesn't have .iteritems() method

Comment: Okay.  I just took a look at the DADict code and altered my solution.

Answer (score 20):

Python's [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) module will do that:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getservbyport(80)
'http'
>>> socket.getservbyport(21)
'ftp'
>>> socket.getservbyport(53, 'udp')
'domain'
```

Comment: I added one more example because, even if you provide the link to the documentation, it will go mostly unnoticed; hope you don't mind. Cheers +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you (filtering the dictionary based on the value):

```
>>> [k for k, v in TCP_SERVICES.iteritems() if v == 80][0]
'www'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unix or linux there is a file /etc/services which contains this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good solution filling another dict self.MYTCP_SERVICES

```
for p in scapy.data.TCP_SERVICES.keys():
  self.MYTCP_SERVICES[scapy.data.TCP_SERVICES[p]] = p
```