# Detect Application layer protocols, python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, packet, scapy

I have a application which capture's and displays the network packets. The packets are represented in two forms in a TableView and as a TreeView. I am using scapy to capture the network packets.

I wish to display the highest protocol level of the packet (highest being application layer for any packet) , the problem that i am facing is that some packets have their final payload named as the protocol itself (for example , DNS payload is named as DNS) , but some payloads are just named as Raw (for example , HTTP payload is named as Raw).

So i was wondering is their any way i could detect these protocols, in python .

This is the output for a DNS packet.

[image]

This is the output for a HTTP packet.

[image]

Here is the code that generates the Tree .

```
def packet2Tree(self,pkt):
    if len(pkt.fields.keys()) == 0 or pkt.name == "":
        return
    self.rootNode = Node(pkt.name , self.RootNode ) 
    field = pkt.fields_desc
    for xfield in field:
        self.childNode = Node(xfield.name , self.rootNode , str(pkt.getfieldval(xfield.name)))
    self.packet2Tree(pkt.payload)
    return self.RootNode
```

Any guess how to solve this problem

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this, but you could look at the port numbers and take a guess? Scapy seems to understand the port numbers for most TCP packets (ie when you call `repr(layer)`) so maybe look to the source?

Comment: @PeterGibson : Put your comment as an answer .

Comment: Did you find in the scapy source where it maps port numbers to names?

Comment: @PeterGibson : yes. Thanks for such a quick reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this, but you could look at the port numbers and take a guess? Scapy seems to understand the port numbers for most TCP packets (ie when you call repr(layer)) so maybe look to the source?

**EDIT** This question explains that the `socket` module can do this for you:

[python-scapy: how to translate port numbers to service names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976599/python-scapy-how-to-translate-port-numbers-to-service-names)

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getservbyport(80)
'http'
>>> socket.getservbyport(21)
'ftp'
>>> socket.getservbyport(53, 'udp')
'domain'
```